# embedded Youtube play button not centered (in Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, iframe, youtube

[image]

This is a screenshot of the **embedded html5 youtube iframe** from my website.

Using chrome dev tools, I dug through the iframe DOM to the **SVG element
(the play button)**.
Giving it **{ width:100%; height:100%;}**  fixes the issue and centers the element.

Of course I cannot do that in code (not same domain).

But maybe I'm missing something?

I haven't seen any questions about this, so I assume I'm doing something wrong.

**this is my iframe:**

```
<iframe id="zoommedia" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/eqFwz_3BikM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" style="height: calc(100% - 48px); opacity: 1;"></iframe>
```

**css for iframe:**

```
.zoomer #zoommedia {

    background-color: rgba(24,24,24,1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 92%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease;
    }
```

I rather not give a direct link to my dev environment, but please let me know if any more info is needed. I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction to get this issue resolved.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us css(#zoomedia)?

Comment: sure, I added the css.

Comment: I think we need a bit more (HTML, CSS, JS) to reproduce the issue. I copied your code in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZGZ8/)**. My recommendation: extend the fiddle until you get the behavior and post the fiddle here. In which browser (and version) are you facing this?

Comment: @FabianMebus Right on sir. Your fiddle reproduces the problem only on chrome/windows (my version:36.0.1985.125 m).. no problem on ie/ff/safari or mac chrome.

Comment: That is weird I am on windows and chrome "36.0.1985.125 m" as well and I am not able to reproduce the described behavior. Maybe a chrome extension. Have you tried to disable some or all of your chrome extension?

Comment: That is very strange, I just disabled all chrome extensions and still get the same result.

Comment: Ok. I checked a co-workers computer and it seems like it's only happening on mine.. if that's the case, I can live with that.. I'll leave this open another day in case someone does see it. thank you.